# VB.net Convert String to Integer with high value

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using VB.net I Need Help what I want is for it to convert the string to integer as shown.

```
    Dim txt12(7) As String

    Dim txt12toint As Integer
    txt12(0) = "048048048048"
    If txt12(0).Substring(0, 1) = 0 Then
        txt12(0) = txt12(0).Substring(1, 11)
    End If
    txt12toint = Convert.ToInt64(txt12(0))
```

However there is always a message stating : 
OverflowException was unhandled
arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
Makesure you are not dividing by zero

I even tried:

```
Cint(txt12(0))
```

and

```
Convert.toint32(txt12(0))
```

but the error to this is the characters are either too long or too short. because int32 is up to 2,147,483,647  one Please if anyone can help thank you in advance

Comment: `txt12toint` is defined as an `Integer`, meaning `Int32`.  You can't poke a 64-bit number into a 32-bit hole.

Comment: that seems to be the problem... Thank very much @SamAxe Love ya!

Comment: related - one should avoid the data types `Long`, `Short`, and `Integer`.  They do not declare intent to the reader as clearly as `Int16`, `Int32`, and `Int64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare txt12toint as Long:

`Dim txt12toint As Long`

This is because 48048048048 exceeds the maximum value for an Integer.

Comment: ... and use [`Long.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: Or Even [Int64.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx) if this is entered by a user

Comment: yeah thanks @Guido Domenici I am having this problem because it is my first time trying vb.net and did forget about the basics